# I have ubuntu with Win 7 how do I ditch Win 7?

Tags: windows

I'm happy to get rid of Win 7 now, how do I do it and will it bring my files over?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Nautilus file manager in Ubuntu and mount the Windows partition.

Copy the files you want to keep to your `/home` folder or to an external drive.

Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select Try Ubuntu without installing.

On the Ubuntu Live desktop open GParted and  delete all Windows partitions.

Boot Ubuntu operating system - open a terminal and execute this command :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now the Windows entry in the GRUB menu and all Windows traces are gone.